# How to get font sizes/types with Adobe X Pro

Tags: adobe, adobe-illustrator, adobe-reader

I work for a university and we have access to the full Adobe suite so software isn't an issue (but I'm not all that familiar with using it).  I'm working with a college who needs to rebuild a PDF using a report builder but there aren't any specifications on how to emulate the PDF.  How could I provide him with some valuable information on spacing and font types and that sort of thing.

Comment: can you please clarify what you mean by "rebuild a PDF using a report builder"?  Also, "emulate the PDF"?

Comment: Sure, there is currently a state government document that people print off, fill in and mail in in order to be processed.  This same document (the said PDF) is going to be put online and we need the online form to be the same as the offline form.  We'll be using Visual Studio 2010 to build the report.  I really just need an easy way to get all the specifics on spacing and font sizes and types.  I have the entire Adobe suite but it's quite the daunting task to learn to use.

Comment: ok... I edited my answer below... hopefully getting closer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* I get what you're going for here...

If you're trying to edit PDFs, Adobe Illustrator or Acrobat are good tools, although they do different things:  Illustrator is a graphic design program, and Acrobat is a business document toolkit.

If you're trying to emulate an existing PDF and need to extract font sizes, typefaces, spacing and such, your task might be as simple as opening the PDF in Adobe Illustrator (PDF is essentially Illustrator's native file format), clicking on the text you want to emulate, and reading the values Illustrator presents to you (**Window** >> **Type** >> **Character** / **Paragraph**).

Using the Control toolbar (**Window** >> **Control**) will make it easier to manipulate and see values.  Also, turn on the [**Rulers**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WSb8134070d1ccd4cc-7ec0f53f124dda9f4a1-8000.html) (Control-R), or use the [**Measure** tool](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6312a.html), if you need to measure arbitrary space in the document.

Comment: i think this will be just about perfect.  i'll have to see when i get into the office tomorrow